# Windows LAN socket connection

Tags: python, windows, macos, sockets, networking

I have two laptops (a macbook pro and a windows 7) in the same LAN.
I try to connect them through socket.

If I use the macbook pro as server and the windows 7 as client, they works fine.

But I need the windows 7 one be the server and it doesn't work.
I'm using python and when my macbook pro is the client and try to connect, I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "renderer_client.py", line 9, in <module>
s.connect(('192.168.56.1', port))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I suspect my windows 7 refuse the connection in the OS level.

I tried to use traceroute connect to my windows 7 directly from my macbook pro, yet it failed.

I guess it's the firewall blocking the connection. I turned off my firewalls in the windows7, but it's still not working. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried stopping all the relevant firewall services? also are you definitely using the IP address of the windows machine?

Comment: @Kash  Yes, I have tried stopping all firewalls. And I'm pretty sure I used the right IP address.